# How can you prevent the triggering specific listeners

Tags: javascript, listeners, eventemitter

I have an issue concerning a project which uses Node's EventEmitter. Consider the following code.

```
let _events = new EventEmitter();
_events.on('test', () => { console.log('Fired foo'); });
_events.on('test', () => { console.log('Fired bar'); });

_events.emit('test');
```

`test`now has two listeners attached to it. Is it possible to add a third which selectively triggers one or the other or both? Every time `test` is emitted both listeners are triggered.

```
_events.on('test', () => { 
    if (a !== b) {
        // prevent other listeners from triggering
    }
 });
```

To give it more context. In my project I have added a listener to a `ClickThrough` event on a videoplayer. The videoplayer itself also has it's own listeners attached. We're both using the same `EventEmitter` object so my listener is in the same array as their listeners. But I want my listener to trigger first and if conditions are met go on to trigger the other attached listener and if not prevent them from firing.

Right now I only see a 'crude' method of caching the listeners and replacing them with a single one which handles the triggering.

```
let _listeners = _events.listeners('test');

_events.on('test', () => { 
    if (a !== b) {
        // prevent other listeners from triggering
    } else {
        _listeners.forEach((fn) => {
            fn.call(this);
        });
    }
 });
```

But this to me doesn't seem like an elegant solution. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Your crude method is the best way to go probably. Else you are listening for one event and doing two different things. If you need a different action you should fire off a different event.